# OpenCV, python - detect and removing objects / buildings in an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to python and opencv. I am analysing images of clouds, and I need to remove the buildings, so that the subsequent analysis will have less noise. I tried using Canny edge detection and then fill in the contours, but did not get too far. I also tried thresholding by pixel colours, but cannot reliably exclude just the buildings and not other parts of the image containing the clouds.

Is there a way I can efficiently and accurately remove the buildings and keep all of the clouds/sky? Thanks for the tips in advance.

Comment: what "analysis" exactly? that determines how (of even if at all!) you should erase those buildings.

Comment: The analysis involves recognizing and subsequently extracting geometric properties of the clouds. The recognition is mainly based on the color properties of individual pixels, and because I am new to computer vision, I thought it would be easier for my analysis if I start by removing the distracting buildings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computer vision model that finds the buildings.  There may be some open source ones out there.  The only one I can think of at the moment is this semantic segmentation model.  There should be details on how to implement it, but there could definitely be others out there.

https://github.com/CSAILVision/semantic-segmentation-pytorch

I think one of the classes is buildings and you could theoretically run the model and get the dimensions of the building and take it out.